# $G = HN$ a group, $N$ normal and $N \cap H =1$. If the conjugacy of $H$ on $N$ has a orbit with all of the non trivial elements: $|N|$ is a prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H, N \leqslant G $ with $N$ normal in $G$ such that $G=HN$ and $N \cap H =\{1\}$. Suppose that all of the non-trivial elements of $N$ are in a single orbit for the conjugacy action of $H$ on $N$, then: exists a prime $p$ such that $\forall x \in N$, $x \neq 1$ we have $|x|=p$.

So I can deduce that the conjugacy action of $H$ on $N$ has two orbits: $\{1\}$ and $N \setminus \{1\}$ and if $x \in N \setminus \{1\}$, for the orbit-stabilizer theorem we have that $|N|-1 = [H:H_x]$, so $|N|-1$ divides the order of $H$, hence $|G| = |N|(|N|-1)k$. Now, to show that $|x| = p\,\,$, I can imagine that the strategy would be to show that $|N|$ is the prime $p$. Any hint will be appreciated since I am stuck here, thank you.

Comment: All the non-identity elements have the same order, and some element of $N$ must have prime order,  so that order must be prime.

Comment: If it helps, $$G=H\ltimes N.$$

Comment: @DerekHolt ah yes, it's clear, $H$ acts transitively on $N \setminus \{1\}$ hence any element has the same order (since conjugacy is a isomorphism of $G$). Thank you

Comment: The problem in the subject line is different from the problem in the post. "There is a prime $p$ such that  nontrivial element has order $p$" is not the same as "$N$ has prime order". The holomorph of the Klein $4$ group is a counterexample to the problem in the subject line.

Answer (score 2):

From hypotheses we obtain: $$N=\{1_G\}\cup\{h n_0 h^{-1}|h\in H\},\;\;\text{ for any } n_0\in N\backslash{\{1_G\}}.$$
Let $n\in N\backslash{\{1_G\}},$ then for a proper $h\in H$ : $$n^{|n_0|}=(h n_0 h^{-1})^{|n_0|}=h n_0^{|n_0|}h^{-1}=1_G.   $$ $$\implies |n|\bigg{|} {|n_0|}\stackrel{\text{simmetry}}{\implies} {|n_0|}\bigg{|} |n|\implies {|n_0|}= |n|.\;\;\; (1)$$
From the Cauchy's theorem exists $n\in N\backslash{1_G}$ s.t. $|n|=p$, for a proper prime (that divides the order of $|N|$), hence from (1), every  non-trivial elements of $N $ has order $p$.

Comment: What is a "proper $h\in H$"? Are there "improper" elements in a group? I think "appropriate" is better there, or "suitably chosen".

Comment: In this case the "improper" elements  $h\in H$ are all elements such that the equality $"n=hn_0h^{-1}"$ it's false.

Comment: You don't need Cauchy's Theorem to prove that a nontrivial finite group has an element of prime order .

Comment: What is another way to prove this?

Comment: To prove what? The fact that every nontrivial finite group has an element of prime order is trivial.

Comment: @Bongo: pick any nontrivial element $x$; let $n$ be the order of $x$. Let $p$ be a prime dividing $n$. Then what is the order of $x^{n/p}$?

Comment: it's $p$, thanks i see now.

Answer (score 1):

The subject line statement is false; it is different from the problem in the body of the post.

As Derek Holt noted, since every nontrivial element of $N$ has the same order (they are conjugate), if $|N|\neq 1$ then there is an element of prime order, and therefore every nontrivial element of $N$ has order that prime $p$. If $|N|=1$, then the statement holds vacuously.

However, this does not mean that $N$ itself is of prime order. That claim is false. For one thing, as phrased in the subject line, $N=\{e\}$ will provide a counterexample by vacuity. But even excluding the case of trivial $N$, the statement is still false.

A counterexample is provided by the holomorph of the Klein $4$-group: let $K=C_2\times C_2$ be the Klein $4$-group, and let $S_3$ act on $K$ by permuting the nontrivial elements. Let $G=K\rtimes S_3$. Then $G$ satisfies the given hypotheses with $N=K$ and $H=S_3$; but $|N|=4$ is not a prime.

Comment: More generally, all affine groups on a finite vector space of dimension greater than $1$ provide a counterexample, as the general linear group is transitive on the non-zero elements.

Comment: How do you know that there is an element of prime order?

Comment: @Devo: Take any nontrivial element $x$. Let the order of $x$ be $n$. Let $p$ be a prime that divides $n$. Then $x^{n/p}$ has order $p$.